# vhost and express - why does't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vhosts

*HI*
I try to serve different content to different domains using express and vhost - but why this does't work ? what's wrong ?

```js
var express = require('express'),
 vhost = require('vhost'),
 app = express();
 

app.use(vhost('test.com'), function(req,res,next){
 app.use('/', require('./test'));
});
app.use(vhost('test1.com'), function(req,res,next){
 app.use('/', require('./test1'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Do you get the wrong content served? Do you get an error message?

Comment: my codes works but - problem is when i start app - form test.com - i have test router (ok) , but when i change host to test1 i have still test , and when i restart app - and start form host test1 i have test1 but when change to test hostname i have still test1 :-(  -